# Исходный код Yandex speller

Tags: java, яндекс-спеллер

Где я могу найти исходный код Yandex speller, обыскал весь интернет, но не нашел, еще один вопрос есть ли yandex speller в качестве библиотеки для java?

Comment: Для прозрения рекомендую поискать ещё исходный код Adobe Photoshop. Чтобы использовать Спеллер из java-приложения подойдёт любая библиотека для осуществления http-запросов, включая [стандартный HTTP Client](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html).

Comment: библиотеки для осуществления  http-запросов меня настораживают. У api яндекса есть ограничения на число запросов, хватит пару тысяч запросов чтобы сервер начинал выдавать ошибку 403, у меня есть серьезные опасения что api яндекса просто не справится с нагрузкой

Comment: Единственный способ использования Спеллера - это http-запросы к его API. Если запросов будет больше 10 000 в сутки, попробуйте запросить у Яндекса коммерческую подписку, либо ищите другой сервис проверки орфографии.

Comment: вобщем то я могу внедрить api яндекса на клиентской стороне, так как я пишу клиент серверное приложение для android и ios. Тогда запросы будут идти не из сервера а из клиентов, а клиенты врядли будут делать 10000 запросов в сутки, но я все равно опасаюсь насколько сервера яндекс справятся с большой нагрузкой